# can you use a custom smtp server with docusignapi in development mode

Tags: smtp, docusignapi

In developing our docusign application, we need to use real emails addresses (to test the addressing logic, etc.) but we do not want those users to get all the development envelopes. In our own code, we handle this using mailtrap.io, a custom SMTP service that traps emails and sends them all to a common inbox that developers can review. Is there a way to do something similar in your docusign developer account, where you would be using real email addresses, but they would not actually go the intended user.

thanks,
~Bill

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. The emails are sent from DocuSign.
If you want to test the real thing, completely real, then it also includes emails being sent.
If you are ok making any change, so it's not 100% like the real thing, I would suggest to take your email address and change the domain (mailinator.com or your own internal domain) this is a change, yes, but also changing the SMTP server is a change, so in either case - you are not doing 100% what the real app will do.
The emails can also be suppressed (by changing account settings in DocuSign), but again, that won't test the real thing if that's what you need.